# way of using elements in list of kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin

I made a code to draw a vector graphic image using HTML Tag <svg>

but I'am stuck while writing a code that received multiple shapes at once through the list.

```
abstract class S(val x: Int, val y: Int, val w: Int, val h: Int,
                     val style: String = "background-color:lightgray") : Renderable {
    abstract fun toDef(): String
    override fun render(notebook: Notebook) = HTML("""
    <svg width="${w}" height="${h}" style="${style}">
        ${toDef()}
    </svg>
    """)
}

// Rectangle
class R(x: Int, y: Int, val width: Int, val height: Int, val fill: String
          ) : S(x, y, x+width, y+height) {

    override fun toDef() : String = 
    """<rect x=${x} y=${y} width=${width} height=${height} fill=${fill} style="opacity: 0.5"/>"""
    
}
// Circle
class C(val cx: Int, val cy: Int, val r: Int, val fill: String
          ) : S(cx-r, cy-r, cx+r, cy+r) {    
    
    override fun toDef() : String = 
    """<circle cx=${cx} cy=${cy} r=${r} fill=${fill} style="opacity:0.5"/>"""
}
```

S is an abstract class that basically has information on the rectangular area occupied by the shape.

R and C are classes corresponding to the rectangular and circular tags of SVG, respectively.

And below code is a code that allows to receive a list(various R and C) and express them in a rectangular area through the toDef() method.

```
class S_Group(val obj: List<S>
        ) : S(0, 0, 200, 200) { 
    override fun toDef() = "" // what should i use? 
}
```

At first, I thought I could use for loop and get() method of the list, but I realized that toDef() is a string action, so I couldn't do this.

Next, I was wondering if I could use Lamda Expression like below, but it didn't work.

> "${o(::toDef())}"

> get Error Message:
> This syntax is reserved for
> future use; to call a reference, enclose it in parentheses:
> (foo::bar)(args)

I couldn't think of any other ideas, so I referred to several questions from stackoverflow and read Kotlin Docs, but I still don't know.

Is there any idea to fill toDef() method of S_Group?

Input and Output Exam:

Input:

> val R1 = R(10,20,80,100,"green")
> val C1 = C(0,30,30,"red")
>
> S_Group( listOf(R1, C1) )

Output what i want:

[image]

Present Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output here?

Comment: @ArpitShukia i add sample input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to somehow combine the values of your list item's `toDef` results, but the way you combine them is up to you.

For instance, you can use [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) this way:

```kotlin
class S_Group(val obj: List<S>) : S(0, 0, 200, 200) { 
    override fun toDef() = obj.joinToString { it.toDef() }
}
```

By default, `joinToString` called like this will create a string by concatenating all the results of `toDef()` of each element, and insert `,`  between each. You can further customize the separator, prefix, and suffix by using more parameters of `joinToString`.

EDIT: I just realized you're generating HTML tags, so you probably want to set the separator to `""` instead of the default `", "`

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't find that. Thank you.

Comment: Because list item's toDef result is format as <circle cx=30 cy=30 r=30 fill=red style="opacity:0.5"/>, i can use default seperator.