# Is there any method something like joinToString for Int in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

[way of using elements in list of kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69915637/way-of-using-elements-in-list-of-kotlin)

Through the answer of the above question, I learned that using joinToString can change the data output format.

I wonder if I can use something similar in the list with item.

```
// data class with Int and String Parameter
data class Person(val age: Int, val name: String) 

// Create a Person object.
val p1 = Person(23, "Smith")
var p2 = Person(41, "Bob")
var p3 = Person(16, "Scott")
// Create a list of Person objects.
val li = listOf( p1, p2, p3 )

// when i want name list of Person list.
println( li.joinToString {it.name} )
> Smith, Bob, Scott 

// But How to get age list(with Type <Int>) of Person list without using loop?
```

Comment: `li.joinToString { it.age.toString() }` Not sure if I'm misunderstanding the question since you already demonstrated you know how to do it with the `name` property.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think OP was missing the `toString()`, and without it the compiler complains that the lambda doesn't return a String. So you should probably write your comment as an answer

Comment: @Sweeper  I think it's right, but I don't know Map well, so I think I should look for it. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on whether you want a new List, or you just want a String with commas in between.

Comment: @Tenfour04 
Sorry, I think I wrote down the question unclearly due to lack of my English skills.
I want to use object as Int type for use method like sum or max. i will edit question

Comment: Then use `li.map { it.age }`. That returns a `List<Int>` so you can use functions like those. You can also do things like `li.sumByOrNull { it.age }` so you don't need an intermediate list.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thx for your help

Comment: Consider adding an answer with the solution so that it can be accepted as the question ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Comment: @João Dias I closed it. Thanks :)